# Validating the type of django queryset related objects parameters

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Does django provide a way to validate the model type in django queryset when for example filtering by related objects? Let's say we have the following models:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=5)

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
```

And

```
p = Person.objects.all().first()
query = Book.objects.filter(author=p)
```

filters all books which auhtor_id is equal to given person_id (p_id), although Book refers to Author, not to Person.

Of course this is the responsibility of a programmer to avoid such errors but it's sitll possible.

This happens in django 1.7

Comment: What happens when you run that code?

Comment: at least in django 1.7 it filters Book by author_id=p.pk

Comment: @pteo It would make more sense for whoever maintains your code to have it filtered by id, and not by the default which is apparently inconsistent across versions. Remember, the two models are not even related in the first place.

Comment: How does this even work?! Person and Author are entirely different models...!!

Comment: @Fazil Zaid don't be surprised. If you don't believe just try it...

Answer (score 2):

```
p = Person.objects.all().first()
query = Book.objects.filter(author=p)
```

Did you actually try this? According to me it should raise a `ValueError` Something along the lines of 'Must be a Author instance"

Now if you want to avoid this error, you need to use an id, and Moses as usual has a good answer showing how it's done.

Comment: at least in django 1.7 it executes without raising any exceptions

Comment: Might have done in 1.7 and I've forgotten, but the current version certainly has this validation.

Comment: The type checking was [added in Django 1.8](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/releases/1.8/#query-relation-lookups-now-check-object-types). Django 1.7 has been end of life for some time.

Answer (score 0):

If `author_id` is same as `person_id` you can *filter* using the id directly:

```
query = Book.objects.filter(author_id=p.id)
```

Comment: I believe it's better to use `p.pk` instead of `p.id`.

Comment: It's a matter of taste

Comment: But `author_id` may be different than `person_id`

Comment: @pteo So how do you expect the two models to be matched? Besides, you can filter with other model attributes `.filter(author__name=p.name)`